# Error uninstalling Nero 7 Ultra Edition (Vista)

Tags: windows, windows-vista, uninstall, nero

I bought a laptop running Windows Vista Home Premium SP1. I didn't touch the pre-packaged Nero 7 Ultra Edition software. When I tried to uninstall Nero through the Windows Control Panel, I saw this error: "this action at this time only applies to products that are installed." I tried a few un-installation programs to remove Nero without success. What can I do?

Answer (score 3):

have you tried the official [**Nero General CleanTool**](http://www.nero.com/enu/tools-utilities.html)?